# ActionController::UrlGenerationError for devise registration controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, rspec-rails

I'm running into an interesting `ActionController::UrlGenerationError` while testing my custom devise `User::RegistrationsController`

Here's the error:

```
 ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"user/registrations", :user=>{:name=>"Adriane Koepp", :city=>"Nidiafurt", :address=>"14955 Cormier Viaduct", :country=>"Mozambique", :email=>"moshe@kozey.com", :phone_primary=>"(295) 491-0447 x9108", :phone_secondary=>"536.985.9499 x7264", :postal_code=>"93438-7448", :province=>"South Carolina", :password=>"MaH9R5G8XqB", :pets_attributes=>[{:name=>"Patches", :chip_number=>"149793073311890", :species=>"iusto"}]}}
```

The error shows up in all my tests for this controller, but for simplicity, I'll only list one test for the `create` action:

```
it 'creates a new User' do
  expect do
    post :create, params: { user: valid_attributes }
  end.to change(User, :count).by(1)
end
```

The `routes.rb` contains:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {
  registration: 'user/registration'
}
```

I can navigate to my registration page just fine at `http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up`, but for some reason, my tests don't seem to think this controller has a valid URL for the `create` action. Why so?

### Additional steps

Upon following D1ceWard's suggestion, I pluralized "registration" in my routes, and now the error message changed to a `AbstractController::ActionNotFound` error. I countered that by following the [documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) and added the following block to the top of my tests:

```
before(:each) do
  @request.env['devise.mapping'] = Devise.mappings[:user]
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is caused by missing pluralization, `devise` don't know what `registration` is, but work with `registrations`.

Solution :

```
# routes.rb
devise_for :users, controllers: {
  registrations: 'user/registrations'
}
```

You can use `rails routes` to check all existings routes.

[Devise doc about custom controllers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Tool:-Generate-and-customize-controllers)

Comment: Hrm, it definitely did something. I now get `AbstractController::ActionNotFound`. Adding details to the question.

Comment: Wait, nevermind, I had to follow more documentation, but that was the solution. Thank you :) I'll complete the answer.